# If two Apache HTTP servers are installed in RedHat, how to make them not disturbing each other

Tags: apache, redhat, bitnami

I have already installed an Apache HTTP server in my RedHat system, now I need to install a Bitnami application package which contains another Apache. So I am wondering how to make them not disturbing each other?

I guess I need to configure different ports for the two HTTP server. But what if one has 8080 and another has 9090, will we visit `http://[ServerName]:8080/something.html` and `http://[ServerName]:9090/something.html`? I think this way is quite inconvenient. Am I wrong or any better idea?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly you cannot do what you are wanting.  Each instance of `Apache` **has** to `LISTEN` on it's own port .. And the only way to let `Apache` *know* which port (or application) to listen to, is to specify it -- and thus the need for the port number in the URL.  How else would Apache know which application to serve to the browser?  If it's *"quite inconvenient"* -- Do what the rest of the world does, and spin up another server and serve them both on whatever port you desire!  And if you don't want the port displayed ..  Serve it on port 80.

Comment: @Zak Apache has virtualhosts that can resolve where to go based on the domain the request is calling for see: [Name-based Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)

Comment: @EndermanAPM -- Wow you must not have read my comment ..  With Name Based Vhost, you **STILL** need to tell it what port to **listen** on ..  IE `<VirtualHost *:9090>` (the port the OP was looking at using) --  Part of his original question was not wanting to use ports in the URL IE `example.com:9090` ...  How does `VirtualHost` solve this exactly?

Comment: The problem that the *OP* has is that he doesn't want to use the ports when browsing the two apps. If he first maps one of the packages to another port and then adds a VirtualHost to the default port one. At use, it will be as they are running on the same port. Also, If someone is using bitnami to manage their apps it's very unlikely they can "spin up another server".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to do something like this.

Have one Apache instance listen in port 80 and the other one in port 8080 for example. The Apache instance that listens in port 80 can act as a proxy to the  other Apache (port 8080) using the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

You would need to define prefixes or virtual hosts and inside them add ProxyPass directives.

Comment: I've never had a use for ProxyPass, but after reading the manual, I can see how it can be really useful.  Have you attempted this personally?  I am curious how this affects overhead?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know to what kind of user those applications are targeted to but the  usual *end-user* is not used to enter ports when browsing the web.

If you like to use the ports, go for it, but I would recommend using [Name-based Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) 
so you could use different domains or subdomains to each application.

In addition to the example provided by the docs (in where they just point to different folders) in [this digitalocean page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache) they document how to make redirects to different urls.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with EndermanAPM that usual end-user is not used to enter ports when browsing the web. Therefore, I would only allow port 80 to be accessed by the end-users.

Additional to the current solutions I see another one:

- avoid messing up the settings of the Apache servers in order to not end-up with some malfunctions of your websites
- leave the Apache servers listen on their designated ports (8080 respectively 9090)
- install a dedicated proxy in front of the Apache servers. The proxy would listen on port 80 and would define redirect rules that would parse the request and would redirect it to the proper Apache server. (see the attached picture)

I recommend you [HA Proxy](http://www.haproxy.org/#docs). It is a very fast and reliable http and tcp proxy. I've been using it in production for years, in front of application servers, web servers and even database servers. Once you get used with its syntax, it is pretty easy to use.

I am aware that introducing a new component into the equation might add another source of potential issues. But I think that the architecture is cleaner. Besides, the two Apache servers will not be disturbing each other as you requested. You can shut down any one of the two and the other one would properly work further.

[image]